# Connect to AWS EC2 after restarting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to stop and restart my AWS EC2 instance daily. I can stop it through the API command line interface, but to reconnect I need to get the new DNS information so that I can connect through Remote Desktop.  Is there a way to reconnect that doesn't involve going through the EC2 Management Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

Assign an [Elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) address to the instance, and always connect via that IP.

You can also then setup a DNS record with a friendly name (e.g. myinstance.mydomain.com) pointing to that elastic IP address.

**Note that while your instance is stopped, having a reserved elastic IP address assigned to it will cost a small hourly charge** - see https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/#Elastic_IP_Addresses for more information.

---

## Option 2

If you're using route53 for DNS management (or some other DNS hosting service which has an API you can use), you could write a script that runs at instance startup which detects its current IP address, and uses the route53 api to update a DNS record with the instances new IP address. You'd need to take into account the DNS propagation time if doing this, so I'd definitely recommend the Elastic IP method over this if possible.

---

## Option 3

Use the AWS CLI with the following commands to get the public IP address of your instance. Be sure to change the instance-id parameter to match your own instance.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id i-0a3bd317964ca45543 --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].PublicIpAddress'
```

For example, combining that with an SSH command might look like this:

```
ssh ec2-user@`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id i-0a3bd317964ca45543 --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].PublicIpAddress' --output text` -i ~/my-key.pem
```

Comment: OK, so this answer partially solved my problem, but now I don't know how to configure Remote Desktop to work with the new associated private IP address.

Comment: Did you assign an Elastic IP address to your instance? And you're trying to connect via remote desktop via the private IP address? Why not the public (elastic) one? What remote desktop software are you using? (Does this seem like an issue with your remote desktop software, or an issue with connectivity to your instance?)